# Replace data in CFC

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a simple CFC page which output data in a JSON format:

```
<cffunction name="test" access="remote" returnformat="plain" output="true">
<cfquery datasource="#dns#" name="rs.q" maxrows="5">
select      text
from        table
</cfquery>

<cfreturn serializeJSON( rs.q ) /> 
</cffunction>
```

The text outputted by the query can contain images, e.g., `/webimages/1.jpg`. Now for the webservice I want to search for images and replace them with `http://domain.com/webimages/1.jpg`.

Can that be done in the CFC file?

Comment: Yes it can.  ReReplace() seems like an appropriate function for this job.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks, but can you provide a small example?

Comment: http://cfdocs.org/rereplace (but as Al says, the simpler [replace](http://cfdocs.org/replace) function may well be enough, and also consider what replace functionality your database offers).

Comment: I was about to suggest using replace in your sql but @PeterBoughton beat me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<cffunction name="test" access="remote" returnformat="json" output="false">
  <cfquery datasource="#dns#" name="local.rs.q" maxrows="5">
    select replace(text, "/webimages/", "http://domain.com/webimages/") as text
    from   table
  </cfquery>

  <cfreturn rs.q> 
</cffunction>
```

or

```
<cffunction name="test" access="remote" returnformat="plain" output="false">
  <cfquery datasource="#dns#" name="local.rs.q" maxrows="5">
    select text
    from   table
  </cfquery>

  <cfreturn replace(serializeJSON(rs.q),
                "\/webimages\/",
                "http:\/\/domain.com\/webimages\/",
                "all")> 
</cffunction>
```